# Problems with the maximum font size in TinyMCE editor on a Joomla website

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I am using TinyMCE as editor on my Joomla website and I have a problem with the maximum font size.

When I insert some text into the TinyMCE editor I can change the font size but the maximum size seems to be: **t (36pt)**, why?

I need to insert larger text into my pages. What can I do to fix?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you could tackle this, but I would try one of these first:

- You can change the dropdown font options using the theme_advanced_font_sizes option, in general, it is something like this:

  ```
  tinyMCE.init({
         ...
         theme_advanced_font_sizes : "10px,12px,14px,16px,24px"
  });
  ```

  For more info on this, [look here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3atheme_advanced_font_sizes).
  Now, since you're using Joomla, you can try to pass your parameters in an array to the display editor call, like is explained in the [official joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getEditor) (keep in mind that you need to check this is one of the adjustable parameters) or you could also try to change the setting for the editor you're interested in by adding some javascript to a specific view, but I'm not sure it'll work. It should be something like: `tinymce.get('editor_id').settings.theme_advanced_font_sizes="10px,12px,14px,16px,24px";`.
  Depending on what you want to do, you could also try using tinyMce indepently or duplicating the plugin with your own tweaks, so that it doesn't get overwritten when you update your site.
- Don't do anything at all. You can control the appearance of any block by inserting css code directly, just use the code view.

Comment: Ok, and in what file I find the tinyMCE.init method call? Tnx

Comment: I've updated my answer, please read again. You have a lot of fun ahead of you, hope you make it work.